# MySQL table displaying strangely

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I imported a csv into a table in a MySQL database, but when I do `SELECT * FROM hale` (where `hale` is the name of the table), I get something that looks like this:

```
+----+--------+------+---------+-----------------+-----------------+----------------------------------------+
| id | Source | Page | Country | Word_ID         | OriginalWord    | OriginalTranslation                    |
+----+--------+------+---------+-----------------+-----------------+----------------------------------------+
                             | | word:HH1885:001 | Siksika         | Blackfeet
                                  |rd:HH1885:003 | oqkatsh         | foot
                                   |d:HH1885:004 | nitokiskam      | one
                                   |d:HH1885:005 | natokam         | two
                                 |ord:HH1885:006 | newowiskam      | three
                                  |rd:HH1885:007 | nijoim          | four
                                  |rd:HH1885:008 | nijitji         | five
                                   |d:HH1885:009 | nawo            | six
                                 |ord:HH1885:010 | ikitchike       | seven
                                 |ord:HH1885:011 | nanisho         | eight
                                  |rd:HH1885:012 | pikkiso         | nine
                                   |d:HH1885:013 | kepo            | ten
                                |word:HH1885:014 | najippo         | twenty
                                |word:HH1885:015 | neppo           | thirty
                           |a  | word:HH1885:016 | kepippo         | one hundred
                                   |d:HH1885:017 | omakkatose      | God
                                |word:HH1885:018 | spouteh         | heaven
                                   |d:HH1885:019 | kristikoy       | day
                                 |ord:HH1885:020 | kokoy           | night
                                   |d:HH1885:021 | matapi          | man
                                 |ord:HH1885:022 | akew            | woman
                                   |d:HH1885:023 | saqkomapi       | boy
```

The csv file is formatted like this:

```
id,Source,Page,Country,Word_ID,OriginalWord,OriginalTranslation
0,HH1885,702,Canada,word:HH1885:001,Siksika,Blackfeet
1,HH1885,702,Canada,word:HH1885:002,siksinam,black
2,HH1885,702,Canada,word:HH1885:003,oqkatsh,foot
3,HH1885,702,Canada,word:HH1885:004,nitokiskam,one
4,HH1885,702,Canada,word:HH1885:005,natokam,two
5,HH1885,702,Canada,word:HH1885:006,newowiskam,three
6,HH1885,702,Canada,word:HH1885:007,nijoim,four
7,HH1885,702,Canada,word:HH1885:008,nijitji,five
8,HH1885,702,Canada,word:HH1885:009,nawo,six
9,HH1885,702,Canada,word:HH1885:010,ikitchike,seven
10,HH1885,702,Canada,word:HH1885:011,nanisho,eight
11,HH1885,702,Canada,word:HH1885:012,pikkiso,nine
12,HH1885,702,Canada,word:HH1885:013,kepo,ten
13,HH1885,702,Canada,word:HH1885:014,najippo,twenty
14,HH1885,702,Canada,word:HH1885:015,neppo,thirty
15,HH1885,702,Canada,word:HH1885:016,kepippo,one hundred
```

And the commands I ran were:

```
CREATE TABLE hale (
  id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  Source nvarchar(255) NOT NULL,
  Page int NOT NULL,
  Country nvarchar(255),
  Word_ID varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  OriginalWord nvarchar(255),
  OriginalTranslation nvarchar(255),
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/pearlh6527/sel_cols.csv'
INTO TABLE hale
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS
(id, Source, Page, Country, Word_ID, OriginalWord, OriginalTranslation);
```

When I select individual columns, however, I see that the information is present in the table. For example, `SELECT Source FROM hale` gives something like:

```
+--------+
| Source |
+--------+
| HH1885 |
| HH1885 |
| HH1885 |
| HH1885 |
| HH1885 |
| HH1885 |
| HH1885 |
| HH1885 |
| HH1885 |
| HH1885 |
| HH1885 |
| HH1885 |
| HH1885 |
| HH1885 |
| HH1885 |
```

Does anyone know why the information might not be displaying correctly when I select everything?

Comment: Can't reproduce. Were there any error while doing `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE ...`?

Comment: Looks like you use Windows-style CSV (CR LF as line break). Test `LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'`

Comment: @FaNo_FN no errors

Comment: @Akina this worked! thank you so much